# active class is adding but not removing the previous menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I am trying to make a menu where the menu item should active scroll wise.
Everything goes perfect except when click next menu item it removes the active class from previous menu class but doesn't add the active class to the new menu

**below are my codes**

```
<div class="row text-center" id="side-menu">
   <nav>
      <ol>
         <li>
            <a href="#page1" class="myanimate">
              <span class="icons iconactive"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span>
              <span class="namee">Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#page2" class="myanimate">
              <span class="icons"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span>
              <span class="namee">Design</span> 
            </a>
        </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#page3" class="myanimate">
              <span class="icons"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span>
              <span class="namee">Review</span>
            </a>
        </li>
     </ol>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**css Active menu**

```
.iconactive{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: brown;
    margin-right: -3.2px;
}
```

**Jquery Codes**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var scrollLink = $('.myanimate');

  // Smooth scrolling
  scrollLink.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     $('body,html').animate({
       scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
     }, 2000 );
   });
     // Active link switching
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();
     scrollLink.each(function() {
      var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top - 20;
      if ( sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation ) {
        $(this).children('.icons').addClass('iconactive');
        $(this).children('.icons').removeClass('iconactive');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are adding and removing the active class from the same element in your jquery part try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var scrollLink = $('.myanimate');

  // Smooth scrolling
  scrollLink.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     $('body,html').animate({
       scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
     }, 2000 );
   });
     // Active link switching
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();
     scrollLink.each(function() {
      var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top - 20;
      if ( sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation ) { 
       $('.icons').removeClass('iconactive');
       $(this).children('.icons').addClass('iconactive'); 
      }
    });
  });
});
```